# Laravel Update / install composer package

Tags: php, laravel, paypal, composer-php

Can you answer me?
I use the latest version of Laravel and I want to add to my project the PayPal service.
I want to install some package to Laravel and added this 2 rows to composer.json

```
"guzzlehttp/guzzle": "~5.2",

"paypal/rest-api-sdk-php": "*"
```

My composer.json file

```
   {
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=7.0.0",
        "fideloper/proxy": "~3.3",
        "laravel/framework": "5.5.*",
        "laravel/tinker": "~1.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "filp/whoops": "~2.0",
        "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
        "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "~6.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "database/seeds",
            "database/factories"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": [
            ]
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "/usr/local/bin/php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "/usr/local/bin/php artisan key:generate"
        ],
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "/usr/local/bin/php artisan package:discover"
        ]
    },
    "config": {
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true,
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
    "cache-dir": "/home/iamdevco/public_html/norrisms/designer/cache"
    },
    "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "~5.2",

"paypal/rest-api-sdk-php": "*"
}
```

but I get this error after download packages

```
$ composer update
```

Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Nothing to install or update
Generating optimized autoload files

> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump
>   /usr/local/bin/php artisan package:discover
>   The system cannot find the path specified.
>   Script /usr/local/bin/php artisan package:discover handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error code 1

Comment: put it in the inside require

Comment: "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "~5.2", that needs to go in the require section

Comment: instead of writing it to composer.json manually you can `run composer require guzzlehttp/guzzle` that way you wont get any composer related errors. You can also define version you want to use

Answer (score 4, accepted):

after you install all packages run

```
composer dumpautoload
```

**packages**

1. [`composer require guzzlehttp/guzzle-services`](https://packagist.org/packages/guzzlehttp/guzzle-services)
2. [`composer require paypal/rest-api-sdk-php`](https://packagist.org/packages/paypal/rest-api-sdk-php)
3. [`composer dumpautoload`](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#dump-autoload-dumpautoload-)

Answer (score 2):

Rather than manually writing the `composer.json`, try installing and adding them with the specific commands. Like this.

```
composer require paypal/rest-api-sdk-php

composer require guzzlehttp/guzzle
```

That way, you'll avoid any typos and `composer.json` file will be kept as pure as possible.

Comment: Thanks for this. but when I run composer dump-autoload this error still issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try this `composer require paypal/rest-api-sdk-php`

Ref: https://packagist.org/packages/paypal/rest-api-sdk-php

Edit:
remove the paypal/rest-api-sdk-php on the composer.json and the guzzle then try this

```
composer require guzzlehttp/guzzle
```